# Ok http is setting unwanted headers in the request by default.

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using HttpURLConnection on android platform.which uses Okhttp internally. I am using delete method, typically delete method does not have the entity body. But I am finding that OkHttp is adding following parameter which I do not have intention to add. like

```
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
"content-length":"0"
```

Is this bug in library why it is adding these header when I did not set these headers ?

Answer (score 2):

Why is it doing it?

Possibly to simplify the code.  Possibly because the implementors didn't look too hard at what happens when you send DELETE requests.

Is it a bug?

That's a matter of opinion.  I think most people wouldn't say it was a bug.  At worst, it is padding the request with a couple of irrelevant headers.  (There is nothing in the HTTP spec that forbids a client or server from including irrelevant headers in a request or response.)

If you really don't like this, submit a bug report to the developers.  Better still, submit a bug report with a properly tested patch.